# My small python app is running a bit slow. Possible bottleneck?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, stock, pysimplegui

Sorry guys for the very newbish question.

I just created a small program using PySimpleGUI and BeautifulSoup which reads live stocks from the TMXMoney website. I know it's quite bad but I am very new to Python (this is my first program actually).

Unfortunately, my program is running a bit slow. When I CMD + Tab to a browser and back to my app, it takes a few seconds for that to go through.

I know I probably have some piece of code that is bottlenecking the whole program, so I was wondering if anybody could help me out in identifying what that bottleneck is?

Here is the code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
import bs4
import requests

def parsePrice(sym):
    r = requests.get("https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=" + sym)     #Canadian stocks source (TSX)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    try:
        price = soup.find("div", {"class":"labs-symbol"}).find("span", {"class":"price"}).find("span").text
        return price
    except:
        return "Cannot find"

sg.theme('DarkBrown1')

layout = [[sg.Input(key="i1",font=('Helvetica', 20),size = (10,0)), sg.Text("0.00",size=(6,0), font=('Helvetica', 20), key="o1")],
       [sg.Input(key="i2",font=('Helvetica', 20),size = (10,0)), sg.Text("0.00",size=(6,0),font=('Helvetica', 20), key="o2")],
       [sg.Input(key="i3",font=('Helvetica', 20),size = (10,0)), sg.Text("0.00",size=(6,0),font=('Helvetica', 20), key="o3")],
       [sg.Input(key="i4",font=('Helvetica', 20),size = (10,0)), sg.Text("0.00",size=(6,0),font=('Helvetica', 20), key="o4")],
       [sg.Input(key="i5",font=('Helvetica', 20),size = (10,0)), sg.Text("0.00",size=(6,0),font=('Helvetica', 20), key="o5")],
       [sg.Input(key="i6",font=('Helvetica', 20),size = (10,0)), sg.Text("0.00",size=(6,0),font=('Helvetica', 20), key="o6")]]

window = sg.Window("TSX Stocks", layout)

while True:                              # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read(timeout=2000)
    if event in (None, 'Quit'):          # if user closed the window using X or clicked Quit button
        break

    if values['i1'] is not "":
        window['o1'].update(parsePrice(values['i1']))
    if values['i2'] is not "":
        window['o2'].update(parsePrice(values['i2']))
    if values['i3'] is not "":
        window['o3'].update(parsePrice(values['i3']))
    if values['i4'] is not "":
        window['o4'].update(parsePrice(values['i4']))
    if values['i5'] is not "":
        window['o5'].update(parsePrice(values['i5']))
    if values['i6'] is not "":
        window['o6'].update(parsePrice(values['i6']))

    time.sleep(1)

window.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause is probably that it's slowing down because it's waiting for all the input. The `submit` button is added and the data is retrieved by pressing it and returned to the event loop.
[github demo program](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/tree/master/DemoPrograms)There are plenty of examples here for your reference.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
import bs4
import requests

def parsePrice(sym):
    r = requests.get("https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=" + sym)     #Canadian stocks source (TSX)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    try:
        price = soup.find("div", {"class":"labs-symbol"}).find("span", {"class":"price"}).find("span").text
        return price
    except:
        return "Cannot find"

sg.theme('DarkBrown1')

layout = [[sg.Input(key="i1",font=('Helvetica', 20),size = (10,0)), sg.Submit(key='-sym1-'), sg.Text("0.00",size=(6,0), font=('Helvetica', 20), key="o1")],
       [sg.Input(key="i2",font=('Helvetica', 20),size = (10,0)), sg.Submit(key='-sym2-'), sg.Text("0.00",size=(6,0),font=('Helvetica', 20), key="o2")],
       [sg.Input(key="i3",font=('Helvetica', 20),size = (10,0)), sg.Submit(key='-sym3-'), sg.Text("0.00",size=(6,0),font=('Helvetica', 20), key="o3")],
       [sg.Input(key="i4",font=('Helvetica', 20),size = (10,0)), sg.Submit(key='-sym4-'), sg.Text("0.00",size=(6,0),font=('Helvetica', 20), key="o4")],
       [sg.Input(key="i5",font=('Helvetica', 20),size = (10,0)), sg.Submit(key='-sym5-'), sg.Text("0.00",size=(6,0),font=('Helvetica', 20), key="o5")],
       [sg.Input(key="i6",font=('Helvetica', 20),size = (10,0)), sg.Submit(key='-sym6-'), sg.Text("0.00",size=(6,0),font=('Helvetica', 20), key="o6")],
        [sg.Quit()]]

window = sg.Window("TSX Stocks", layout)

while True:                              # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event in (None, 'Quit'):          # if user closed the window using X or clicked Quit button
        break

    if event == '-sym1-':
        symbol = values['i1']
        price = parsePrice(symbol)
        window['o1'].update(price)
    if event == '-sym2-':
        symbol = values['i2']
        price = parsePrice(symbol)
        window['o2'].update(price)
    if event == '-sym3-':
        symbol = values['i3']
        price = parsePrice(symbol)
        window['o3'].update(price)
    if event == '-sym4-':
        symbol = values['i4']
        price = parsePrice(symbol)
        window['o4'].update(price)
    if event == '-sym5-':
        symbol = values['i5']
        price = parsePrice(symbol)
        window['o5'].update(price)
    if event == '-sym6-':
        symbol = values['i6']
        price = parsePrice(symbol)
        window['o6'].update(price)    

#     time.sleep(1)

window.close()
```

Comment: Upon reviewing your code today, I was very disappointed that the way you modified my app, the stocks I am getting now no longer update in real time. Rather, I have to manually click "Submit" to get the newest stock quote.

Comment: Simply put, I think it's the heaviness of the real-time processing and the lightness of the processing each time.Simply put, I think it's the heaviness of the real-time processing and the lightness of the processing each time.